# Can we add thousands separator for reputation tooltip in stack exchange grid view

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stackexchange.com, tooltips, numbers

Can we add thousands separator for the reputation tooltip in the Stack Exchange [grid view](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#), for each site's top user's reputation tooltip. It will increase the number readability.

Currently the thousands separator is added for the numbers in the **questions**, **answers** and **users** tooltip, but not for the user reputation tooltip.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Grid view]

Expecting the thousands separator which is similar to the tooltip in the [/users](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) page:

> [image: users page]

Comment: How do you even find these issues ... kudos to you! ;)

Comment: Isn't that thing called a "thousand(s) seperator"?

Comment: @Luuklag Thanks. I have updated in the post.